# segfault when using -static and -fopenmp in gfortran

Tags: static, segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp

i am using openmp in fortran and before the program gets much done at all, it runs into a segfault by simply trying to write to a line as seen below:

```
783       module Lines
784 
785       character*80 eline, dline
786 
787       contains
788 
789       subroutine InitializeLines
790       print*, 'writing to eline'
791       write(eline,'(1x,79(''#''))')
792       print*, 'writing to dline'
793       write(dline,'(1x,79(''-''))')
794       end subroutine InitializeLines
795 
796       end module Lines
```

in the main routine, when i try to call `InitializeLines`, it simply prints out `writing to eline` before giving me a segfault. Now, the program runs perfectly fine when i compile without `-fopenmp`. Note also, that there is only one thread active in this section (a simply `get_num_threads()` reveals that I am entering `InitializeLines` with only one thread). As soon as i take off `-fopenmp`, there is no segfault and the program executes correctly.

note also that i have a `-DUSEOPENMP` flag in my makefile for when i want to use openmp. if i have not defined that, then no openmp actions will take place. this is important because when i compile *without* `-DUSEOPENMP`, but *with* `-fopenmp`, i get the same segfault problem even though i am 100% sure i am not even calling any extra threads or using any part of openmp.

Now, with a bit of playing around i have found that this problem goes away when i take out the `-static` as a compilation option. my question is - why? why is it that `-static` and `-fopenmp` don't work together and is it a problem that i can address in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [glibc specific problem](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39176) – static linking doesn't play well with threaded programs, including OpenMP. There is a workaround though: force the linker to link the whole `libpthread.a` archive and not only the directly referenced symbols with `-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive`.

Unless you have a really good reason to link system libraries statically, don't do that.